# linux change some string in file AND encrypt it at the same time

Tags: linux

wanted to quickly on 100s of files encrypt values with base64, I know about sed but is there a way to quickly do some command on the found string or do I have to do it manually `cut -d: -f2 | cut -c 4-` and then encrypt and write back all data again

```
data:
- name: stringa
  value: valuea
- name: stringb
  value: valueb
```

change them to

```
data:
- name: stringa
  value: dmFsdWVh
- name: stringb
  value: dmFsdWVi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacky but it works

```
cat file | grep value | cut -d ":" -f2 | while read values; do echo -n "${values}:" && echo -n $values | base64;done > values && cat ./values | while read values; do sed -i "s/$(echo $values | cut -d ":" -f1)/$(echo $values | cut -d ":" -f2)/g" ./file;done
 && rm -rf values
```

Assumption file content is

```
data:
- name: stringa
  value: valuea
- name: stringb
  value: valueb
```

Output

```
ebvjr@Maintenance:~/work/stackoverflow$ cat file
data:
- name: stringa
  value: valuea
- name: stringb
  value: valueb
ebvjr@Maintenance:~/work/stackoverflow$ cat file | grep value | cut -d ":" -f2 | while read values; do echo -n "${values}:" && echo -n $values | base64;done > values && cat ./values | while read values; do sed -i "s/$(echo $values | cut -d ":" -f1)/$(echo $values | cut -d ":" -f2)/g" ./file;done && rm -rf values
ebvjr@Maintenance:~/work/stackoverflow$ cat file
data:
- name: stringa
  value: dmFsdWVh
- name: stringb
  value: dmFsdWVi
ebvjr@Maintenance:~/work/stackoverflow$
```